# Flink 1.1.3 Interact with Hive 2.1.0

Tags: apache-flink, apache-hive

Excuse me for the inconvenience but I did not find an answer in the Doc or Internet.

I have a platform with :

- Hadoop 2.7.3
- Hive 2.1.0
- Hbase 1.2.4
- Spark 1.6

I have integrated Flink 1.1.3 to use it on local mode and Yarn mode.

I'm interested to use Flink with Hive (As hiveContext with Spark) to read data in scala-shell, is it possible ? And How ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Flink does not support direct connections to Hive as it is supported in Spark with SQL context. But there is a simple way of analyzing data in Hive table in Flink using [Flink Table API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/table_api.html)

What you need to do is first get the exact HDFS location of the Hive table you wish to analyze with Flink e.g.

```
hdfs://app/hive/warehouse/mydb/mytable
```

Then you read data

```
DataSet<Record> csvInput = env
            .readCsvFile("hdfs://app/hive/warehouse/mydb/mytable/data.csv")
            .pojoType(MyClass.class, "col1", "col2", "col3");
```

Then you need to create a table from the DataSet and then register it with the TableEnvironment

```
Table mytable = tableEnv.fromDataSet(csvInput);
tableEnv.registerTable("mytable", mytable );
```

And now you are all set to query this table using Table API syntax.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/deshpandetanmay/mastering-flink/tree/master/chapter04/flink-table) to the sample code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From Flink 1.9.0, we are officially supporting Flink with Hive. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/table/hive/

are you still looking into this option?